# try to get content in google plus from China

Tags: google-plus

I am a developer from China where we cannot access content from google plus or facebook due to some "special reason(been blocked)", and I want to get some wonderful content from google+, and put them into my online education website, all content is about learning knowledge.

So my first solution is: call google+ api to get these content, then store them into my site DB(of course, I will write clearly where those are from), but this solution is only for the text, for images, most of them were stored in googleusercontent.com(which is also blocked in China), and I don't want to download these images then store to my own website(overload is too big).

I want to transfer these pictures into other websites(not been blocked in China),  then I noticed site: getpocket.com can save image from other websites, and they seem have some cache, can I use this feature? after get image url from google+, then call getpocket api to save this image, but don't know where api will return the cached image url), is it possible do this?

Does anyone have good solution for this images? so I can transfer these good learning knowledge to Chinese people?

(google+ activity api like this: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/108305986241738899171/activities/public?maxResults=20&key=)

thanks everybody

Comment: another solution is:  store image into base64 string into DB, then read it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use mongoDB to store image which will be transfer to base64 string. e.g: http://www.tomylearn.com/netTest/index/listInfonews.do?categoryid=47